# How to migrate and keep same Username and Password from Prestashop to Magento?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, prestashop, database-migration, magento2

I am migrating my Shop from Prestashop to Magento. 
So I want to keep all user's Login details same after migration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are migrating from a Prestashop to Magento then the most important thing is to migrate User’s Usernames and Passwords. If you will use this method, you will be able to use Same login after migration. **

To get the migrated passwords from Prestashop to Magento working, we need go through these 2 steps:

**Step 1**
Export customers from Prestashop.

In Prestashop, there is no straight forward method to export customers password, but you can always write your custom query to get the reuired information from database. Login to Prestashop admin section go to Advanced Parameters->SQL Manager and write a new sql query “select email, firstname, lastname, passwd from ps_customer; “ which will be used to select customers email id, firstname, lastname and password from customer table. If you want to select more fields, write your sql query accordingly. Afterwars export the information in csv file.

**Step 2**
The process through which Prestashop and Magento creates customer password is slightly different. Prestashop uses ‘Cookie Key’ prefix to the customer password, which is then MD5 encrypted. Magento uses MD5 and salt at the end. It’s not possible to convert passwords to plain text once it is encrypted using MD5 , so we need to rewrite customer authentication model to extend default validation process and validate passwords imported from Prestashop by adding prefix Cookie Key value to the passwords which was used to generate passwords in Prestashop.

Rewriting Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Model

1. Create a module with namespace Retailon and modulename Customerimport
2. Enable your Module in app/etc/modules/Retailon_Customerimport.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Retailon_Customerimport>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Retailon_Customerimport>
</modules>
</config>
```

3. Create config.xml file app/code/local/Retailon/Customerimport/etc/config.xml with following content:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Retailon_Customerimport>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</Retailon_Customerimport>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<customer>
<rewrite>
<customer>Retailon_Customerimport_Model_Customer</customer>
</rewrite>
</customer>
</models>
</global>
</config>
```

4. Create model file app/code/local/Retailon/Customerimport/Model/Customer.phpwith following content:

```html
<?php
class Retailon_Customerimport_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer {

public function authenticate($login, $password)
{
$this->loadByEmail($login);

if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
);
}
if (!$this->validatePassword($password) && !$this->validatePassword('u4qrHpFiADz3peo8rS5tBkWARaa2WqN3qa7XqCI8iddIo7gdbj3KPNzGyK0'.$password)) {
throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
);
}
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
'model' => $this,
'password' => $password,
));
return true;
}
}
```

5. You will see a long string prepended to the password variable in authenticate method, which is the cookie string used to generate passwords in Prestashop. 
   Go to config/settings.inc.php
   file of your Prestashop project’s directory and you will see a line like

```html
define('_COOKIE_KEY_', 'u4qrHpFiADz3peo8rS5tBkWARaa2WqN3qa7XqCI8iddIo7gdbj3KPNzGyK0');
```

Copy this string and replace the cookie sting of your Magento’s authenticate function.

That’s all you need to do.

Now you should be able to login to Magento store using your Prestashop credentials.

**Happy Reading!**

P.S. You can read full post here as well:

Credit: How can I transfer and keep same Username & Password from Prestashop to Magento? by Ankur Makadia on Website | iOS & Android App | Games | ERP | CRM (https://webappexperts.quora.com/How-can-I-transfer-and-keep-same-Username-Password-from-Prestashop-to-Magento)

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash functionsuch as MD5 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Sir! @zaph

Comment: Sorry about digging this topic from underground but; do we have a magento 2 equivalent to this ?